# Navigate to requested page after login

Tags: jsf, url, jakarta-ee, servlets, primefaces

I know this issues has been discussed so many times, however, I did not manage to get it straight. I would really appreciate if you would take a look at this.

So, I have following issue:

If a user wants to acces my application through a link e.g.

```
http://example:8080/Kundenportal/protected/post/post.jsf
```

he will be redirected to my loginPage(I have a Phaselistener which validate if logged in or not).

Now, after the login, the user wants to get to

```
http://example:8080/Kundenportal/protected/post/post.jsf,
```

instead he will be redirected to

```
http://example:8080/Kundenportal/protected/post/start.jsf.
```

How can I tell my application where the user should be redirected after the login? I know it works through HttpRequestServlet, however after checking if loggedIn or not in the Phaselistener the user will be redirected to my loginpage, that means the requestURL is loginPage, which is wrong.

Here is my code.

This is my PhaseListener:

```
@Override
public void afterPhase(PhaseEvent event) {
    FacesContext fc = event.getFacesContext();
    String currentPage = fc.getViewRoot().getViewId();

    HttpServletRequest origRequest = (HttpServletRequest) fc
            .getExternalContext().getRequest();
    //  Here is the requestURI post.xhtml 
    String reqURI = origRequest.getRequestURI();

    // boolean loginPage = page.startsWith("/login.xhtml");
    // boolean registerPage = page.startsWith("/registrierung.xhtml");

    boolean loginRequired = currentPage.startsWith("/protected/");
    if (loginRequired && !loggedIn(fc)) {
        NavigationHandler nh = fc.getApplication().getNavigationHandler();
        nh.handleNavigation(fc, null, "loginFAILED");
        fc.renderResponse();

    }

}
```

Ok, now this is how I set up the faces-confing.xhtml:

at.ooev.kp.controller.login.LoggedInCheck

```
<application>
    <locale-config>
        <default-locale>de</default-locale>
        <supported-locale>de</supported-locale>
    </locale-config>
    <message-bundle>at.ooev.kp.messages</message-bundle>
    <resource-bundle>
        <base-name>at.ooev.kp.messages</base-name>
        <var>messages</var>
    </resource-bundle>
</application>  
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>loginFAILED</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>doLogin</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/login.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>EXPIRED</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/expired.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>  
</navigation-rule>

<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>*</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>PAGE_0_</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/protected/start.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>PAGE_1_1</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/protected/pol/polizzen.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>PAGE_1_2</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/protected/sch/schaden.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>PAGE_1_3</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/protected/tk/topkundeninfo.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>PAGE_2_</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/protected/daten/daten.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>PAGE_2_1</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/protected/daten/kundendaten.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>PAGE_2_2</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/protected/daten/benutzer.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>PAGE_3_1</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/protected/post/post.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>PAGE_4_1</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/protected/komm/vereinbarung.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>PAGE_5_1</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/protected/trans/transport.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>

<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>loginOK</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/protected/start.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>register</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/registrierung.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>loginPOST</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>/protected/post/post.xhtml</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

And  this is my managedBean whith the login:

```
@PermitAll
public String login() {
    FacesContext fc = FacesContext .getCurrentInstance();
    HttpServletRequest origRequest = (HttpServletRequest) fc.getExternalContext().getRequest();
    // The requestURI is here login.xhtml(because there was the redirection in the Phaselistener)
    String str = origRequest.getRequestURI();

    if (doLogin(credentials.getUsername(), credentials.getPassword())) {
        String realname = (!Utils.isEmpty(webbaUser.getVorname())) ? webbaUser
                .getVorname() + " "
                : "";
        realname += webbaUser.getName();
        user.setUsername(credentials.getUsername());
        user.setRealname(realname);
        user.setKndnr(credentials.getUsername());
        if ("kunde".equalsIgnoreCase(credentials.getUsername()))
            user.setKndnr("600828");
        user.setMailadresse(webbaUser.getEmail());
        user.setHostUserid(webbaUser.getHostuserid());

        HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest) FacesContext
                .getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest())
                .getSession(false);
        session.setAttribute("LOGGEDINUSER", user.getUsername());
        dbLog.add(DbLogController.Aktion.LOGIN, user.getUsername());
        // List<String> kundennummern = webbaUser.getDatfilt();
        // for (String s : kundennummern)
        // System.out.println("datfilt: " + s);
        return "loginOK";
    } else {
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                new FacesMessage("Anmeldung fehlgeschlagen!"));
        dbLog.add(DbLogController.Aktion.LOGINFAILED,
                credentials.getUsername());
        user = null;
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep your URL in a session attribute like LOGIN_REDIRECT in your phase listener and use it after login.

Some frameworks like spring security will do that for you.